# Function continues looping in controller when using $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im relatively new on Angular so i dont know if this is the best solution. 
But I have this state/route with a button, when clicked this function is called:

```
_this.foo = function () {
    save();
    $state.go("next");
}
```

The problem is that when i get to the next state with the same controller, the function is still ongoing so it saves the next page to.Thats not what I want, i want it to save the first one, and then go to the next one and stop.

**Edit:**
I have several forms in a list, every form has a approval button and disapproval button. When function save() is called all forms in the list is approved and saved to back-end. And then it redirects to the next page, but my app continues to save the next list of forms to.

Could i pass some parameter to the $state.go for it to stop the function? I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: What exactly does `save()` do?

Comment: Does this work? `$state.go("next", $state.params, {reload: true});`

Answer (score 0):

Angular when save data in the backend, should be return a **promise**. When this promise are resolved, then i could be change of a other state.

```
_this.foo = function () {
    save().then(function(){
      //In this point the promise it's already resolved
      $state.go("next");
    });  
}
```

possible `.save()` implementation

```
 function save(){
    //where $http.post returns a promise
    return $http.post('your_api/resource/:id');
 }
```